# Array sorting using a provide string only sort the first word of each array value

Tags: javascript

Array sorting using a provide string only sort the first word of each array value

I am developing a webpage once a user input some strings in the text field and the it with sort out  the result from an array of data. It should be sort the first string of the value which match the input first in alphabetical order. However, the result is only sort the first word of the value, start the second word, the order was reversed. How can I sort every word in an array ? Is there any thing wrong with my code ?

```
const data = [
  "DALIAN YI DA PRECISION RUBBER PRODUCTS CO., LTD.",
  "DALIAN TOSHIBA TELECISION CO.,LTD",
  "DALIAN SHENGFU BUSINESS FORM PRINTING CO.,LTD",
  "DALIAN SHENGFENG INTERNET OF THINGS TECHNOLOGY INC",
  "DALIAN OKEN SEIKO CO., LTD.",
  "DALIAN MATSUMOTOSHO TRADING CO.,LTD.",
  "DALIAN JINGSHIHENG ELECTRONIC TECH. CO., LTD.",
  "DHDC",
  "DALIAN HENGFENG ELECTRONIC TECH. CO., LTD.",
  "DALIAN GEETON ELECTRONICS CO.,LTD ",
  "DALIAN AUPAC CO.,LTD.",
  "DALIAN ALPS TEDA LOGISTICS CO.,LTD.",
  "CHIYODA INTEGRE (DALIAN) CO LTD",
  "HUICHANG LOGISTICS (BONDED LOGISTICZONE DALIAN CO",
  "MATSUYA R&D (DALIAN) CO., LTD.",
  "MIKURO SPRING (DALIAN) CO.,LTD",
];

const inputValue = "DALIAN";

data.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.startsWith(inputValue.toUpperCase) && a>b) {
      return 1;
    } else if (a.startsWith(inputValue.toUpperCase)&& a<b){
        return -1
    }else{
        return 0
    }
});

console.log(data);
}
```

result:

```
 [
'DALIAN YI DA PRECISION RUBBER PRODUCTS CO., LTD.',
'DALIAN TOSHIBA TELECISION CO.,LTD',
'DALIAN SHENGFU BUSINESS FORM PRINTING CO.,LTD',
'DALIAN SHENGFENG INTERNET OF THINGS TECHNOLOGY INC',
'DALIAN OKEN SEIKO CO., LTD.',
'DALIAN MATSUMOTOSHO TRADING CO.,LTD.',
'DALIAN JINGSHIHENG ELECTRONIC TECH. CO., LTD.',
'DHDC',
'DALIAN HENGFENG ELECTRONIC TECH. CO., LTD.',
'DALIAN GEETON ELECTRONICS CO.,LTD ',
'DALIAN AUPAC CO.,LTD.',
'DALIAN ALPS TEDA LOGISTICS CO.,LTD.',
'CHIYODA INTEGRE (DALIAN) CO LTD',
'HUICHANG LOGISTICS (BONDED LOGISTICZONE DALIAN CO',
'MATSUYA R&D (DALIAN) CO., LTD.',
'MIKURO SPRING (DALIAN) CO.,LTD'
]
```

Comment: I suggest reading [some documentation on how `sort` works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#description). Returning -2 only doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I know the compare function is compare the unicode value of a and b. if return positive number a will sort after b and so on. The -2 is just a testing value. The original code is something like this 
data.sort((a, b) => {
  if (inputValue && inputValue.length > 0) {
    if (a.startsWith(inputValue.toUpperCase) && a>b) {
      return 1;
    } else if (a.startsWith(inputValue.toUpperCase)&& a<b){
        return -1
    }else{
        return 0
    }
  }
});

console.log(data);

if the array value is start with the input string, it should sort before another value.

Comment: So I just put a negative number if the validation is true. And from the result, the array start with what I input - i.e. "DALIAN", it all sort at the beginning of the array. However, start from the second word - i.e. DALIAN "YI"..., DALIAN "TOSHIBA"..., it as sorted in reversed alphabetical order: Y -> T ->  S -> O -> M ...
Sorry that I am new on programming and cannot figure out the logic on the array sorting method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sort mechanism isn't correct. First of all, you're comparing strings so use [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare). Here is a basic example using your data:

```js
let data = [
  "DALIAN YI DA PRECISION RUBBER PRODUCTS CO., LTD.",
  "DALIAN TOSHIBA TELECISION CO.,LTD",
  "DALIAN SHENGFU BUSINESS FORM PRINTING CO.,LTD",
  "DALIAN SHENGFENG INTERNET OF THINGS TECHNOLOGY INC",
  "DALIAN OKEN SEIKO CO., LTD.",
  "DALIAN MATSUMOTOSHO TRADING CO.,LTD.",
  "DALIAN JINGSHIHENG ELECTRONIC TECH. CO., LTD.",
  "DHDC",
  "DALIAN HENGFENG ELECTRONIC TECH. CO., LTD.",
  "DALIAN GEETON ELECTRONICS CO.,LTD ",
  "DALIAN AUPAC CO.,LTD.",
  "DALIAN ALPS TEDA LOGISTICS CO.,LTD.",
  "CHIYODA INTEGRE (DALIAN) CO LTD",
  "HUICHANG LOGISTICS (BONDED LOGISTICZONE DALIAN CO",
  "MATSUYA R&D (DALIAN) CO., LTD.",
  "MIKURO SPRING (DALIAN) CO.,LTD",
];
const inputValue = "DALIAN";
data.sort((a, b) => a.split(' ')[0].toUpperCase() == inputValue ? a.localeCompare(b) : 1);

console.log(data);
```

But it appears you want to take the input, sort based on the first word match, then have the others (which also contain the word, just not first) to appear after those. In that case, you need to maintain 2 sorts and combine them at the end. I used Array.reduce to assist:

```js
const inputValue = "DALIAN";
let data = [
  "DALIAN YI DA PRECISION RUBBER PRODUCTS CO., LTD.",
  "DALIAN TOSHIBA TELECISION CO.,LTD",
  "DALIAN SHENGFU BUSINESS FORM PRINTING CO.,LTD",
  "DALIAN SHENGFENG INTERNET OF THINGS TECHNOLOGY INC",
  "DALIAN OKEN SEIKO CO., LTD.",
  "DALIAN MATSUMOTOSHO TRADING CO.,LTD.",
  "DALIAN JINGSHIHENG ELECTRONIC TECH. CO., LTD.",
  "DHDC",
  "DALIAN HENGFENG ELECTRONIC TECH. CO., LTD.",
  "DALIAN GEETON ELECTRONICS CO.,LTD ",
  "DALIAN AUPAC CO.,LTD.",
  "DALIAN ALPS TEDA LOGISTICS CO.,LTD.",
  "CHIYODA INTEGRE (DALIAN) CO LTD",
  "HUICHANG LOGISTICS (BONDED LOGISTICZONE DALIAN CO",
  "MATSUYA R&D (DALIAN) CO., LTD.",
  "MIKURO SPRING (DALIAN) CO.,LTD",
];

let arrs = data.reduce((b,a) => {
if (a.split(' ')[0].toUpperCase() == inputValue) b[0].push(a)
else b[1].push(a)
return b
},[[],[]])

const sortme = arr => arr.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b));

let newdata = sortme(arrs[0]).concat(sortme(arrs[1]));
console.log(newdata)
```

Comment: It works, Thanks.
Can you explain more about the array.reduce method ?
Thanks so much